# Python jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-swarm

I have an `api.py` script on a docker container, using python3 and docker-compose.

Dockerfile:
    FROM python:3-stretch
    COPY files /app/files
    WORKDIR /app
    CMD ["python", "files/api.py"]

In my `api.py` i have a code that is supposed to run `render_template`:

```
return render_template('button.html')
```

I have a `templates` dir in files dir, and it does work if i cd to files and then run my `api.py`.

But, as this is in docker container and i run the script from outside the file:

`CMD ["python", "files/api.py"]`

so thats why i get this error, how can i over come this?

I tried to work from inside of `files` dir but i get errors. I also tried to `os.chdir` before `return redner_template` and it also didnt work.

```
├── files
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── templates
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens if you change to this: `WORKDIR /app/files`?

Comment: my bad, i had docker registry and i didnt push so i didnt saw changes..now works.

Comment: Ah, ok. Glad you fixed it :)